# how to get infinite scroll with remote data with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, api, infinite-scroll

Currently i am developing a listings portal here i am using `angularjs` as frontend and through this i am calling `api` to load data right now when a user hit all listings link whole data is loading and showing at this point the data is very less so problem but if data is large it will take some loading time, my requirement is when a user first click the link it has to show only top 50 listings and if user scrolls down the page then again `api` has to call for next 50 listings and so on how can i achieve this with `angularjs`.

Comment: take a look at [angular-nicescroll.](https://github.com/tushariscoolster/angular-nicescroll) It has `nice-scroll-end` option. You can call your function to fetch next 50 listings.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
$scope.limit=50;
$scope.loadMore1=true;
$scope.count=0;
$scope.loadMore=function()
{
    $scope.limit=$scope.limit+100;
    if($scope.limit>=$scope.count) {
        $scope.loadMore1=false;     
    } else {
        $scope.loadMore1=true;
    }
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
}
```

Inside your ajax call or api call

```
if(result.data.items.length<=50)
{
    $scope.loadMore1=false;
} else {
    $scope.count=result.data.items.length;
    $scope.loadMore1=true;
}
```

And finally HTML list which loads certain number of results

```
<li ng-repeat="r in results | limitTo:limit"></li>
<button class="loadMore" ng-show="loadMore1" ng-click="loadMore()">Load more Items...</button>
```

Comment: i want to call the list api dynamically after user scrolls down to bottom of page without button.